# Selecting only first div class

Tags: jquery

I have an early form of an app which allows you to be set goals, and you can then accept them. Each goal has an individual unique ID which allows it to be identified and accepted by making its "accepted" field in the database '1'.

Each goal is its own iteration of the following code:

```
<div id='goal'>
<div class='setby'>Set on $timeset by $name</div>
<div class='goal'>$goal</div>
<div class='completeby'>Complete by $goaltime.</div>
<form id='acceptGoal' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' class='id' name='id' value='$gid'>
<input type='button' class='submit' value='Accept?'></button>
</form>
</div>
```

My problem is that whichever goal I accept on a page of many, jQuery only ever returns the ID of the first in the list. I tried changing the `id` fields of the `<input>`s into `class` fields, but this hasn't worked, and have also tried other fixes like `[id=id]` and `[class=id]`, and am subsequently completely stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

**script.js**

```
$('.submit').click( function() {
    var data = $("[class=id]").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "accept.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data: "id="+data,
        success: function(response){
            $("[id=result]").html(response);
            },
        error: function(response) {
            alert("error");
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
var data = $("[class=id]").val();
```

to:

```
var data = $(this).prev().val();
```

You need to select the input relative to the one clicked on, which this will do. If for some reason the order of inputs might change, you could also do:

```
var data = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="id"]')val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot have duplicate `id`s on `form` elements.

*You are not even supposed to have duplicate `id`s on a page.*

Attach to the submit event on your form elements instead and serialize all the input within it in a single operation:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();    // Stop the normal form postback
     var data = $(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "accept.php",
         datatype: "json",
         data: data,
         success: function(response){
             $("[id=result]").html(response);
         },
         error: function(response) {
             alert("error");
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: No comment on this version? It is always better to serialise the form, if present, than send a single field. The effect is the same on the server as id=val for your one field but more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

First: what's up with this selector

```
$("[class=id]").val()
```

Change that to:

```
$(".id").val()
```

As TrueBlueAussie stated you should never have multiple of the same id's on one page. For getting the value of your form field you can use:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    //Prevent an actual submit from happening
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get the value of the field with classname id in this form
    var data = $(this).find('.id').val();

    //Do your AJAX awesomeness here
});
```

$(this) is used to scope finding the form field to just this form and not the first occurrence somewhere on your page.

Comment: This seems like a much better way of doing it, but now I've made these edits, the data doesn't get submitted to accept.php at all. Thoughts?

Comment: At the line that says "//Do your AJAX awesomeness here" you should make your AJAX call as you put it in your example.

Comment: No, that's what I've done - it still doesn't work :P

Comment: Your AJAX call states the type is JSON, but it isn't.

You can send the value through an object.

`var data = {};
data.yourdata = "the identifier";`

Set that as your data param and remove the datatype json from your ajax options. You can read the data in your PHP file through `$_POST['yourdata'];`